# MySQL get quiz score from quiz with questions having multiple correct answers

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a quiz score from my database, basically a quiz question can have multiple correct responses but for that response to be counted as a correct answer the user must select all the correct answers for the question.

E.g. if the user only checks 1 answer that is correct but the quiz question has multiple options that are correct then the user answer is considered incorrect and not counted.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id              INT(10)             AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email           VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    fullName        VARCHAR(100)        NOT NULL,
    password        VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    admin           TINYINT(1)          DEFAULT 0,
    active          VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    resetToken      VARCHAR(255)        DEFAULT NULL,
    resetComplete   VARCHAR(3)          DEFAULT 'No',
    dor             TIMESTAMP, /* dor = Date of Registration */
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unit (
    id          INT(10)         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    published   TINYINT(1)      DEFAULT 0,
    unit_img    INT(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (unit_img) REFERENCES files(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
    id          INT(10)         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    file_name   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    loc_name    VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz (
    id      INT(10)         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    unit_id INT(10)         NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    published   TINYINT(1)      DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (unit_id)   REFERENCES unit(id)     ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz_question (
    id                  INT(10)         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    quiz_id             INT(10)         NOT NULL,
    question            VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    -- correct_answer      INT(10)         NOT NULL,
    question_img        INT(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id)           REFERENCES  quiz(id)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (question_img)      REFERENCES  files(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quiz_answer (
    id  INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL,
    question_id INT(10)         NOT NULL,
    choice      VARCHAR(150)    NOT NULL,
    is_correct  TINYINT(1)      DEFAULT 0, -- If = 1 then it is a correct answer
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id)   REFERENCES  quiz_question(id)   ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE user_quiz_answers (
    id int(10)          AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id int(10)     NOT NULL,
    question_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    answer int(10)      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)       REFERENCES  users(id)           ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id)   REFERENCES  quiz_question(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (answer)        REFERENCES  quiz_answer(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `fullName`, `password`, `admin`, `active`, `resetToken`, `resetComplete`, `dor`) VALUES (NULL, 'test@gmail.com', 'Gerald', 'abc123', '1', 'YES', NULL, 'No', current_timestamp());

INSERT INTO `unit` (`id`, `name`, `published`, `unit_img`) VALUES (NULL, 'Motorbike', '1', NULL);

INSERT INTO `quiz` (`id`, `unit_id`, `name`, `published`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Final Exam', '1');

INSERT INTO `quiz_question` (`id`, `quiz_id`, `question`, `question_img`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Which parts of a motorbike should be lubricated?', NULL);

INSERT INTO `quiz_answer` (`id`, `question_id`, `choice`, `is_correct`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Chain', '1');
INSERT INTO `quiz_answer` (`id`, `question_id`, `choice`, `is_correct`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Break lines', '1');
INSERT INTO `quiz_answer` (`id`, `question_id`, `choice`, `is_correct`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Tyres', '0');

INSERT INTO `user_quiz_answers` (`id`, `user_id`, `question_id`, `answer`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', '1');
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(uqa.question_id)) FROM user_quiz_answers uqa
LEFT JOIN quiz_question qq ON uqa.question_id=qq.id
LEFT JOIN quiz_answer qa ON uqa.answer=qa.id
WHERE uqa.user_id=1 AND qq.quiz_id=1 AND uqa.answer IN (SELECT qa.id FROM quiz_answer qa WHERE qa.is_correct=1);
```

qa.is_correct (0 = not a correct answer, 1 = is a correct answer)

The above is what I have so far, this almost works except it is counting an answer as correct as long as the user gets one of the options in the question correct which is when i want this to be considered incorrect and not counted.

EDIT:
Basically I need to check the the following two queries to return the same result:

```
-- GET correct answers for question
(SELECT qa.id FROM quiz_answer qa WHERE qa.is_correct=1 AND qa.question_id=1);

-- Get user answers for question
(SELECT uqa.answer FROM user_quiz_answers uqa WHERE uqa.question_id=1 AND uqa.user_id=1);
```

EDIT 2:
Here is an SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ac0f/1

Comment: @Strawberry thankyou, I've editted my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code will solve your issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (uqa.question_id))
FROM user_quiz_answers uqa
JOIN quiz_question qq 
  ON uqa.question_id = qq.id  
WHERE uqa.question_id NOT IN (SELECT a.question_id 
                              FROM      (SELECT qa.question_id,
                                                qa.id 
                                         FROM quiz_answer qa 
                                         WHERE qa.is_correct = 1) a
                              LEFT JOIN (SELECT uqa.question_id,
                                                uqa.answer 
                                         FROM user_quiz_answers uqa ) b
                                     ON a.question_id = b.question_id 
                                    AND a.id = b.answer
                              WHERE b.answer IS NULL
                              UNION
                              SELECT a.question_id 
                              FROM (SELECT qa.question_id,
                                           qa.id 
                                    FROM quiz_answer qa 
                                    WHERE qa.is_correct = 0)  a
                              JOIN (SELECT uqa.question_id,
                                           uqa.answer 
                                    FROM user_quiz_answers uqa) b
                                ON a.question_id = b.question_id 
                               AND a.id = b.answer  )
  AND quiz_id = 1 
  AND user_id = 1;
```

---

**Explanation**: This part of the code will fetch the question ids where all the answers is not checked.

```
SELECT a.question_id 
FROM      (SELECT qa.question_id,
                  qa.id 
           FROM quiz_answer qa 
           WHERE qa.is_correct = 1) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT uqa.question_id,
                  uqa.answer 
           FROM user_quiz_answers uqa) b
       ON a.question_id = b.question_id 
      AND a.id = b.answer
WHERE b.answer IS NULL
```

Next part of the code will fetch all the question ids where incorrect option is checked

```
SELECT a.question_id 
FROM (SELECT qa.question_id,
             qa.id 
      FROM quiz_answer qa 
      WHERE qa.is_correct = 0)  a  
JOIN (SELECT uqa.question_id, 
             uqa.answer 
      FROM user_quiz_answers uqa) b
  ON a.question_id = b.question_id 
 AND a.id = b.answer
```

Now we got all the incorrect question ids. So we are removing this question ids from  user answers table (`WHERE uqa.question_id NOT IN`) and counting the remaining questions which gives the correctly answered question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, this appears to work for a single question of question_id= n. But say I want it to return the total score for the whole quiz (quiz_id= n)?

Comment: Verify the updated code where I removed the question id filter and now you can also filter based on quiz id and user id

Comment: Hi, This query is working perfectly on my local XAMP mysql database but when I re-create on my live website I'm getting an error. The same error occurs for me when running through SQL Fiddle, do you know why this might be?

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ( SELECT a.question_id FROM ' at line 15`

Comment: I too posted the code after testing in xamp. Now I removed extra parenthesis wrapped on the union blocks which I had previously and it works now. Hope it helps